# LWC Component unable to get response from Nager.Date API although response is shown in network tab

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, cors, csp, get

I am unable to get the response from Nager.Date API using the follow code:
LWC function:

```
getData(){
    let myurl = 'https://date.nager.at/api/v3/publicholidays/2021/AU';
    fetch('https://date.nager.at/api/v3/publicholidays/2021/AU', {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: 
            { 
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
            } 
      })
    .then( response => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify('response '+JSON.stringify(response)));
        return response.json();
    }).then(jsonResponse => {
        console.log('hello');
        console.log(jsonResponse);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error ',JSON.stringify(error));
    })
}
```

CSP and CORS are already setup in the dev org, and while observing the networks tab, i see the proper response but, the response seems to still null.
Screenshot of network tab:
[image]

Screen shot of console log:

[image]

any ideas what is going on?

Function is called in the connectedCallback() if that helps.

Comment: ` response seems to still null` what variables is null? you seem to be printing out several things in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`no-cors` prevents you from getting the response values in JavaScript (a so-called "Opaque" response). This is a security/privacy feature. See [this Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182785/why-fetch-return-a-response-with-status-0). The server would have to be enabled to support CORS, which it appears is not the default. Presumably, they expect you to run your own. You should be able to spin up a server on [Heroku with Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) after enabling the CORS feature (see the README for details). This is not a Salesforce-specific problem, as [LWC OSS](https://lwc.dev/) also [can't read the data](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/SRVtezhKk1JH3zOj7Wcs/src/app.js).

Comment: Thanks, i added the no-cors option to prevent some CORS related error without understanding what it is doing, upon further investigation, seems like this is behaving as expected and the developers of the api intended us to run our own server.